# Changing the value of final static member of a nested static class

Tags: java, reflection

When I try to change the value of a static final member of a nested static class  I don't see it working. When I try the below code to change the static final member of some other class it works.

```
   public class FinalPivateStaticMember {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Initial value == "+Test.val);
            try {
                Class cls = Class.forName("com.reflection.FinalPivateStaticMember$Test");
                try {
                    Field file_systems_loaded = cls.getDeclaredField("val");
                    file_systems_loaded.setAccessible(true);

                    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
                    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        System.out.println("--"+file_systems_loaded.getModifiers());
                        modifiers.setInt(file_systems_loaded,file_systems_loaded.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
                        System.out.println("--"+file_systems_loaded.getModifiers());
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        file_systems_loaded.setBoolean(null,false);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.print("Final value == "+Test.val);

        }

        static class Test{

           private  static final  boolean val = true;
        }

    }
```

#### Output of above code

```
Initial value == true
--26
--10
Final value == true
```

Comment: maybe that using a getter is somewhat different than accessing the field directly... The compiler is known for 'inlining' constant values, actually if you change a constant field (`public static final`) in one class and do not recompile other classes that use that field, they will still have/use the old value.

Comment: this is explained in the Java Language Specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9-300

Comment: As a side note, `Class.forName("com.reflection.FinalPivateStaticMember$Test")` doesn’t gain you anything over the much simpler `Test.class`.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger of course, using a getter doesn’t change anything, the access within the getter method gets inlined as any other access. But besides the fact that `val` is a compile-time constant, modifying `static final` fields is off specification anyway and not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is actually changing, but you don't see the change in your print statements because of compiler optimization.
The compiler can (and will) replace the occurrences of primitive (and `String`) static final fields with the value they hold. So after compilation your print statements would be equivalent to

```
System.out.print("Final value == "+true)
```

Note that the variable is replaced with it's source value during compilation phase itself.

Comment: The behavior regarding compile-time constants is more than an optimization, it’s a mandatory behavior. Since string concatenation with compile-time constants results in a compile-time constant as well, the actual compiled code is equivalent to `System.out.print("Final value == true");`…